# Cannot load jade view using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to create a jade view and load it using express. The path `/` loads correctly, but when I load the `helloworld` the browser says `Cannot get /helloworld`.

I have created the following view and saved it to views:

```
extend layout

block content
    h1=title
    p Hello! Hello World! Welcome to #{title}
```

In `routes/index.js` I did this:

```
exports.helloworld=function(req,res){
res.render('helloworld',{title:'Hello World!'});
};
```

And in the `app.js` file:

```
app.get('/helloworld',routes.helloworld);
```

## UPDATE:

The full `app.js` file:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
   ,routes = require('./routes')

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
 app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
 app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/helloworld',routes.helloworld);
app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,     app.settings.env);
 });
```

My `routes.js`:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};

exports.helloworld=function(req,res){
res.render('helloworld',{title:'Hello World!'});
};
```

The `layout.jade` did not have a `block content`,adding it to `layout.jade` instead of `body!=body` causes this error:

```
    Error: /home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/views/layout.jade:7
5|     link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
6|   body
```

> 7|  #content
>       8|       block content

```
 Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both
 at Object.Lexer.indent (/home/anr/Desktop/node  
 js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:762:15)
 at Object.Lexer.next (/home/anr/Desktop/node  
 js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:870:15)
 at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/home/anr/Desktop/node 
 js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:114:46)
 at Parser.lookahead (/home/anr/Desktop/node 
 js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:100:23)
at Parser.peek (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:77:17)
at Parser.tag (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:733:22)
at Parser.parseTag (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:719:17)
at Parser.parseExpr (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
at Parser.block (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:689:25)
at Parser.tag (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/withdb/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:806:26)
```

So,indenting with spaces instead causes an empty page to load.This is my current `layout.jade`:

```
 doctype html
 html
  head
   title= title
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
   block content
```

`Sublime Text` indents with `four spaces` for a `Tab`.

Comment: I don't think the error you're getting is template rendering related. Most likely your `app.get` is in the wrong place. What does your full `app.js` file look like?

Comment: can you post your full routes file? Also is it `Cannot get \helloworld` or `Cannot get `/`helloworld` ?

Comment: @Kiran updated `routes/index.js`

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in jade file: extend layout should be extends layout

Comment: Write an answer @Kiran so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments,
 `extend layout` should be `extends layout`.

FYI, if you have access to the server logs, this should be displayed in the dev environment.

Comment: updated the `layout.jade` with `block content`,fixed indentation and tried to load `helloworld`,get a blank page.Could you please check your post and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this question hasn't been answered in 8 months, but for those of you looking for help still, I believe the problem lies with the line:

```
res.render('helloworld',{title:'Hello World!'});
```

which should read

```
res.render('index',{title:'Hello World!'});
```

because what follows will utilize the index router.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In `/routes/index.js` change this:

```
exports.helloworld=function(req,res){
  res.render('helloworld',{title:'Hello World!'});
};
```

to this:

```
exports.helloworld=function(req,res){
  res.render('index',{title:'Hello World!'});
};
```

will work like a charm!

OR Else...

create a `helloworld.jade` file in views folder. **This is more recommended.**

Both the solutions are technically correct though!